# Circle using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

How can I draw a Circle using tikz?

I'm practicing tikz, but I can't draw this one, it's difficult for me.

Any help?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the manual: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: More specifically, you can follow the section 2 of PGF Manual.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), then the community could help you on the parts where you are stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are zillions of ways of drawing this. IMHO it makes sense to store the radius and the angle in functions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R=5;theta=30;},line join=round]
 \draw (0,0)coordinate[label=below:{$(0,0)$}] (O) circle[radius=R]
 (90:R) node[above]{$\theta$};
 \draw (90+theta:R) coordinate[label=above:{$z^*$}] (z*)
  -- node[below=1ex] {$1$}(O) -- node[below=1ex] {$1$}
  (90-theta:R) coordinate[label=above:{$w^*$}] (w*)
  -- node[above] {$2\sen(\frac{\theta}{2})$} coordinate (p) cycle;
 \draw[dashed,angle radius=1.25cm,pic actions/.append style={draw}] 
    pic{angle=O--z*--w*}
    pic{angle=z*--w*--O}
    pic[pic text={$\theta$},angle eccentricity=1,
    pic text options={anchor=south west}]{angle=w*--O--z*}
    (O) -- (p);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!